# how to submit the order of items with jquery sortable function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list of 22 drivers. I need to order them according the result of a race. To do this I want to use a sortable function from jQuery. This looks OK. Now there is only one problem. When I am ready with the order of items I want to submit it to a PHP page. How can I submit it.

A working example is here http://jsfiddle.net/UVeB6/

to make the list of items i do this

```
<ul id="sortableQual">
    <li id="qual_1" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>S Vettel<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_2" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>M Webber<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_3" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>F Alonso<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_4" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>F Massa<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_5" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>J Button<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_6" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>S Perez<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_7" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>K Raikkonen<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_8" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>R Grosjean<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_9" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>N Rosberg<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_10" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>L Hamilton<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_11" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>N Hulkenberg<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_12" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>E Gutierrez<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_14" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>P di<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_15" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>A Sutil<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_16" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>P Maldonado<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_17" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>V Botta<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_18" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>J Vergne<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_19" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>D Ricciardo<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_20" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>C Pic<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_21" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>G van<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_22" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>M Chilton<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
    <li id="qual_23" class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>J Bianchi<font size="1" style="float:right;"><sub>qual</sub></font>

    </li>
</ul>
```

But how can I submit the `<li>` order? With alert I can see the order

```
stop: function (event, ui) {
            alert($(this).sortable('serialize'));
        }
```

but instead of an alert I need it to submit it to a PHP page.

Comment: I'd use ajax to send it to php, or place it in a hidden input in an existing form and submit that.

Comment: You already got it: serialization is the keyword. Use `$.post` or something similar (like a hidden input if you want a submit) then to get it to your PHP site

Comment: This has nothing to do with `sortable()`. It's no different from submitting any other value in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you should do something like this. (Very generic answer without knowing more details)

```
stop: function (event, ui) {
            $.get('some url', { someParam : $(this).sortable('serialize')}, function(){
                 do something on callback complete
            });
        }
```